# Taking a key from a hash, and interpolate that as a getter on an object

Tags: ruby, getter, string-interpolation, instance-methods, string-to-symbol

I have a class that creates objects. I've created getter/setter methods for that class.

```
Class Test

  attr_accessor :method1, :method2, :method3, :method4
```

I have created several instances from that class, and appended them to a list

```
@object_array = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

I have a dictionary that contains the keys and values. The keys have the same string value that the instance variables in the test class use. (For example 'method1' exists as :method1) I would like to access those keys as the getter methods.

```
@method_hash = {'method1' => ['data1','data2'], 'method2' => ['data3','data4']}
```

I expect this to work, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

I should mention that the method below is taking place inside a class and that @object_list and @method_list are themselves instance variables of this second class. (This might not be relevant to solve the issue, but wanted to mention just in case..)

```
block (2 levels) in func1': undefined method `key' for #<Obj:0x007ffbe1061870> (NoMethodError)

  def func1
    @object_array.each do |o|
      @method_hash.each do |key, value|
        puts o."#{key}"
      end
    end
  end
```

I tried using .to_s, .to_sym to get it to work with no luck.

Comment: `puts o.instance_variable_get("@#{key}")` or `puts o.send(key)`

Comment: `puts o.public_send(key)`

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts o."#{key}"` is syntactically wrong. You need to fetch the property on runtime. For this you can:

```
puts o.instance_variable_get("@#{key}") # dynamically inspect instance variable
# above will only work if key is instance variable and not a method of o.
```

or

```
puts o.send(key) #dyanmic dispatch
# will work as long o responds to the key like o.method1.
```

**Update:** Prefer `o.public_send(key)` over `send` to dynamically dispatch only the publicly accessible method/attribute, as it is safer inspection of object without leaking it's private content.

If you are sure that is an instance variable, go with the safer first option.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ call to `to_s` inside a string interpolation is redundant: it’s called by ruby automatically. Also, prefer `public_send` over `send` wherever possible.

Comment: yes. I agree. I updated the answer to add a note for this. Thanks @mudasobwa!